# weather.gov API expired forecast grid

Tags: java, weather-api

I've got a program that pulls a list of forecast links using the [weather.gov API Web Service](https://www.weather.gov/documentation/services-web-api) and then calls each link in order to pull and store weather data for zip codes, which can they be viewed on our home page based on a Users zip code preferences. Lately I'm seeing a lot of 503 errors in our error log, so when I went to check it out and run a few of the URLs using Postman, I am getting the following response:

```
{
    "correlationId": "36eb9a42-990d-4ca8-a24a-cd0c67985903",
    "title": "Forecast Grid Expired",
    "type": "https://api.weather.gov/problems/ForecastGridExpired",
    "status": 503,
    "detail": "The requested forecast grid was issued 2020-02-11T02:50:40+00:00 and has expired.",
    "instance": "https://api.weather.gov/requests/36eb9a42-990d-4ca8-a24a-cd0c67985903"
}
```

Unfortunately I do not know what it means when a requested forecast grid expires, and I could not find anything in their documentation for this, either. Maybe I've missed something, or maybe I've got a problem in my code that's causing this issue.

This is a java program and it uses javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection and java.net.URL:

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/BOX/21,35/forecast");
HttpsURLConnection httpsConn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
httpsConn.setRequestMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
httpsConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpsConn.setConnectTimeout((1000 * 60));
httpsConn.setReadTimeout((1000 * 60));
StringBuffer response = getApiResponse(httpsConn, 0);

private StringBuffer getApiResponse(HttpsURLConnection httpsConn, int counter){
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    try{
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpsConn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        counter++;
        errorLog.add("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        errorLog.add("Number of attempted calls: " + counter);
        if(counter < 5){
            response = getApiResponse(httpsConn, counter);
        }else{
            errorLog.add("Max attempts made for this API Call.");
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

I wrapped the call within a function that will try to make the call 5 times, as I noticed while building this program that sometimes the call just simply times out. The url I used just happens to be one of the ones I am having trouble with, it seems to be that anywhere involving `BOX` is causing the above 503 error.

Has anyone else encountered an issue like this - and how did they solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out that this is not something we can solve ourselves. While a 503 Status Code means that the server being called is unable to handle the request (and I know that it's not a fault on our end) I was perplexed by the error message being received and was wondering if it had anything to do with the way I had set up my call to the service.

This error message basically boils down to a service outage, which means there isn't anything we can do on our side except report the outage and wait for a result.

I feel silly marking this as the answer since it boils down to "contact their support system" but maybe if anyone comes across this in the future they'll at least know the reasoning - but hopefully they'll improve their error messages so that it's more clear what is a service outage and what is an issue with the call you made.

Comment: The status code itself conveys what you're looking for, as defined by the HTTP specification.

Errors in the 400-499 range indicate a client-side issue; the request was invalid in some way and cannot be handled as sent.

Errors in the 500-599 range are used to indicate a server-side error; your request was valid but cannot currently be serviced for some reason.

A lot of web services like to butcher these (like always returning 500) which results in confusion, but as the lead designer of this particular API I can assure you that we do use the HTTP error codes for their intended meanings.

Comment: @StephenClouse thank you for your response. What I was trying to get at was just the fact that while the 503 code made sense, the detail message of the code was confusing to me and I did not know how to proceed from there. For me, it was more that the detail message was not helpful in telling me what the actual problem was.

Comment: @Conrad37 To help consider better alteratives, how do you interpret the meaning of "has expired" in the context of a forecast?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/weather-gov/api/discussions/370 and https://github.com/weather-gov/api/discussions/371